# How to populate a reactive table with a FormGroup inside a FormArray inside a FormGroup

Tags: angular

After check of all the similar answers and a full day of tries I still need help with a reactive table created with a nested FormGroup-FormArray-FormGroup structure.

I have a json with this structure (I'm hand writing it, maybe is inaccurate, but this is not the problem, it's just an example) for translations and need to have a modal form to change the translations:

```
{
   "code":"APPLE",
   "description":"Apple translations",
   "translations":[
      {
         "language":{
            "code":"en",
            "description":"English"
         },
         "value":"Apple"
      },
      {
         "language":{
            "code":"it",
            "description":"Italian"
         },
         "value":"Mela"
      },
      {
         "language":{
            "code":"de",
            "description":"Deutch"
         },
         "value":"Apfel"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need a modal form with a head containing the first 2 fields (code-description) disabled.
Then, under this, a table with 3 rows containg English-Apple , Italian-Mela , Deutch-Apfel

I've tried almost all the solutions I've found here in StackOverflow, without success. Still trying to understand what's wrong.

**EDIT:** I'm not familiar with StackBlitz but I've done this
[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k5ynfp](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k5ynfp)
Now I'm trying to make it at least compile...

On this row (locally, not on StackBlitz)...

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of form.controls.translations.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

... there is an error: "[Angular] Identifier 'translations' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member"

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? Without one it becomes difficult to debug.

Comment: I'm not familiar with StackBlitz but I've done this --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k5ynfp
Now I'm trying to make it at least compile...

Comment: On stackblitz I don't get the error "[Angular] Identifier 'translations' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member". I can't believe it. ç_ç